# How to reference filter fields in a data table using column names which are written in a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project where I need to filter data based on a certain value and column name mentioned in another sheet

My data is in the sheet called as "Inclusion Sheet" and the table name is "Inclusion"

I have Written the following code

```
'''
    Dim r1 As Integer

    r1 = Rows("1").Find("MatchA").Column

    Sheets("Inclusion Sheet").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("Inclusion").AutoFilter Field:=r1, Criteria1:="TRUE"
'''
```

In this r1 is directly using the cell name "MatchA". I want to change this so that the value of r1 is based on cell A1 which is written in another sheet (say Sheet1) than the data table itself.

So if I change the value of the cell A1 in sheet 1, the value of r1 should change accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim r1 As Long 'don't use integer, integers are Longs cut to an integer
    Dim MySearch As String 'here you will get the string you are looking for

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        MySearch = .Range("A1") 'If I understood your question, the column you are looking for is in Range A1 from Sheet1
    End With
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inclusion Sheet")
        r1 = .Range("Inclusion").Find(MySearch).Column
        .Range("Inclusion").AutoFilter Field:=r1, Criteria1:="TRUE"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @PratyakshAgrawal Glad it helped, please consider marking this as correct answer so others may find it.